# Error on migrating from springfox to OpenApi

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

I recently moved my project from springfox to OpenAPI using [this tutorial](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html)

But it doesn't mention which are the imports that should be used and I have now started getting hundreds of errors like

```
java:16: error: cannot find symbol
@Schema
```

---

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String @ApiResponse(responseCode=400, response=ApiError.class)
```

---

```
error: cannot find symbol
            @Parameter(paramType="query", name="id")
```

What are the imports to be used to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try import from `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations*`

Some examples:

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.ParameterIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.operation;
```

More examples here https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi